# What are those tildes in gVim for?

Tags: gvim, characters

I realize this is probably a very, very obvious question, but I couldn't find *anything* on it. (Probably because it was so obvious)

What are all those tildes in gVim at the end of the file? I can't edit them or anything, but I assume they mean *something*.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They show you where a line *isn't* - that there is nothing there, yet.  As opposed to a line without one, which shows you a [line that contains nothing](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html#02.1).

Comment: if that's the case, why don't they go away one-by-one as I enter new lines and fill up the window? Instead, they just move down and elongate the scroll bar, giving the appearance of more to the document when it's really just more tildes.

Comment: I have no idea, but those are the semantics of that tilde in vim.

Comment: Could you link me to some sort of reference for that? (or some generic reference that'll have it)

Comment: I honestly can't supply one, beyond https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/screen.c#1996

Comment: @ThomasShields: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html#02.1